# Renaming an array created by Array.new

Tags: ruby

When creating a new array in IRB, I can use `Array.new` to get an empty, unassigned array.

Is there a way to reassign that new array? Can I turn, `[]`  into a variable named `my_new_array`?

I know I can do this:

```
my_new_array = Array.new
```

Or I can do:

```
my_other_new_array = []
```

But what about reassigning `Array.new`?

I'm new to Ruby and I'm curious about this little nuance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IRB, the underscore `_` method will give you the results of the last expression:

```
Array.new
# => []
my_new_array = _
# => []
Array.new(2, "foo")
# => ["foo", "foo"]
my_new_array = _
# => ["foo", "foo"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Now if you type something else in the IRB, then your opportunity to name Array.new is lost right?

Comment: Yes, it'll only take the last-executed statement.